# What does the Android drawing cache do in the background?

Tags: android, caching, path, draw

I have an application which requires me to draw paths to a canvas.  As the number of paths builds up, the cumulative drawing action takes longer, so I thought I would improve speed by using the drawing cache.

To do this I have an `onDraw` method looking a bit like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path;
    Paint paint;
    synchronized(mPaths) {
        buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp = getDrawingCache();
        if(bmp!=null) canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,
                new Rect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight()),
                new Rect(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom()),
                null);
        for(int i=mLastCount; i<mPaths.size(); ++i) {
            path = mPaths.get(i);
            paint = mPaints.get(i);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
        mLastCount = 0;
        mDrawn = true;
        destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}
```

`mPaths` and `mPaints` are lists of `Path` and `Paint` objects and I have a method set up to work out how many are new so it only redraws the last one.  I originally called `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` instead of `buildDrawingCache()` and `destroyDrawingCache()` but this didn't work (that may be significant).

Anyway, this code works—it produces a bitmap which I can write to the canvas, then I only draw the last path and everything is fine *except* that as I draw more and more paths, it still slows down, as though it were still redrawing all the paths during `buildDrawingCache()`.

Is that what's happening?  Ideally I would like the draw method to be blitting a bitmap, then placing a single path over it.  If it's generating the bitmap from all the paths, every time, I might as well not bother (in fact I will probably write my own bitmap generation code if this is the case, but it seems a pain).

If it *isn't* what's happening, is there something else that could be causing the code to slow down?